# What are the differences in "debug as" vs exported APK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, paypal

No lint markers. The paypal sdk component works completely fine when debugging through every device I've plugged into my computer through eclipse. When I export the project as an APK it "Unfortunately stops" when I get to the paypal part of the app. What would be the key differences in a debug run vs a compiled apk file? Again the live payment services are working fine in the project when run as debug. There are no API keys that are sensitive to SHA1 differences in this project (signed apk vs debug).

Here is a little of what's going on I can see from the report from the app installed from the apk:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='onEdgeUpdate'   signature='(Lio/card/payment/DetectionInfo;)V' in class Lio/card/payment/CardScanner;
at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:418)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:359)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
at io.card.payment.CardScanner.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at io.card.payment.z.c(Unknown Source)
at io.card.payment.z.a(Unknown Source)
at io.card.payment.CardIOActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at io.card.payment.CardIOActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the debug mode when I press the checkout button it works fine, but here is what is in the logcat, maybe someone can see something:

```
09-11 12:43:32.932: D/dalvikvm(10630): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libcardioDecider.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.932: D/dalvikvm(10630): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libcardioDecider.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.932: D/dalvikvm(10630): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_core.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.932: D/dalvikvm(10630): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_core.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.942: D/dalvikvm(10630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_core.so 0x4219ac28, skipping init
09-11 12:43:32.942: D/dalvikvm(10630): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_imgproc.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.942: D/dalvikvm(10630): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_imgproc.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.942: D/dalvikvm(10630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libopencv_imgproc.so 0x4219ac28, skipping init
09-11 12:43:32.942: D/dalvikvm(10630): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libcardioRecognizer.so 0x4219ac28
09-11 12:43:32.952: D/dalvikvm(10630): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.direction.investor.bcms-2/libcardioRecognizer.so 0x4219ac28
```

Comment: Is your method onEdgeUpdate() declared in an xml in onClick attribute of a button?

Comment: I think Nitin nailed it. It's probably a proguard obfuscation problem. You could either add a proguard setting that protects that method or you should remove any kind of method name reference from your XML files (better option) and set on click listeners etc. in code.

Comment: @NitinSethi I don't recognize this method. It must be part of the paypal library as it certainly isn't in any of my xml files. The app doesn't stop exactly when I press the checkout button, the paypal component flashes on the screen very briefly.

Comment: @NobuGames    I never thought about ProGuard. I bet I left something out. Probably this: at proguard-paypal.cnf .. Thanks

Comment: Have you saved the mapping.txt file that is one of the outputs resulting from Pro-guards obfuscation. You could get more information about the source of issue as you could be sure what those z.c and z.a are. More details on mapping.txt here. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#considerations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to developer.android, "The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer."

I had failed to include the:

```
 @proguard-paypal.cnf marker in the proguard-project.txt
```

For future reference on the android paypal sdk please see https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK.